# EC2 ssh permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have create key pairs : EC2 > Network & Security > Key Pairs > Create key pair (RSA, .pem)

I have download file and change chmod :

```
chmod 400 file_key_pair.pem
```

I have try this command :

```
ssh -i file_key_pair.pem root@<Public IPv4 DNS>
```

```
The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-224-146-117.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.224.146.117)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:yWiX5WQUZpHawHGDrYo1gQvwCcrVhT3jbEavgMXoQ88.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

When i write "yes", i have this response :

```
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-224-146-117.compute-1.amazonaws.com,54.224.146.117' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@ec2-54-224-146-117.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I have try with username root and ec2-user but that don't work.

Comment: This doesn't put the key onto the machine.  That needs to be done by hand.  See [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-key-pair.html) for details.

Comment: You would typically supply the keypair when you launch the EC2 instance, in which case you would be able to SSH to it.  Also, note that a typical Amazon EC2 instance will not allow SSH as the root user.

Comment: What is the actual error you’re receiving? As an aside, the username is dependent on your image and OS… For example, an AWS Linux AMI login will be `ec2-user`, a Bitnami AMI will have a login of `bitnami`, and an Ubuntu AMI will have a login of `ubuntu`.